# Laravel 5.2 Eager Loading with multiple level one to may relationship

Tags: php, laravel-5

I'm  new to laravel and I'm using Laravel 5.2 I want to have all the comments of a particular post of a user. My tables are like :

```
User
-----
id

public function posts() {
   $this->hasMany( 'App\Posts' )
}

Post
------
id
user_id

public function user() {
   $this->belongsTo( 'App\User' )
}

public function comments() {
   $this->hasMany( 'App\Comment' )
}

Comments
----------
id
post_id

public function post() {
   $this->belongsTo( 'App\Post' )
}
```

Now what I want is to get all the post for a perticular user say the logged in user. I can get all the comments by the long way like :

```
$comments = [];
foreach( Auth::user()->posts as $post) {
    foreach( $post->comments as $comment ) 
    {
       $comments[] = $comment->title
    }
}
```

But I was wondering how to get the comments without making these loops using the relations only. Thanks in advance.

Comment: $post->comments will return a collection of comments. You could then either call toArray() on that or you could possibly use pluck if you only needed one field in the array, keyed by the id, e.g: $post->comments->pluck('title', 'id');

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/collections#method-toarray

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can double the relationship from the existing user object:

```
$posts = \Auth::user()->posts()->with('comments')->get();
```

It should work for all levels.

In my project I have Organizations with Clients with a link table to Therapists, all multiple, and this works:

```
Organization::find(1)->clients()->with('therapists')->get();
```

so your case should work too. Let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially you want to **eager load** your data using `with()` and dot notation like so:

```
$user = User::with('posts.comments')->find(Auth::user()->id);
```

If you just want the comments, you can do:

```
$user = User::with('comments')->find(Auth::user()->id); 
$comments = $user->comments();
```